# How to link azure api connections to an azure logic app using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, connection, azure-logic-apps

How do I link created azure api connections to an azure logic app using powershell, the logic app requires 2 sql api connections to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct cmdlet to do that. You need to first have the definition created (json format) which needs to have those connections. Refer

- [Schema reference guide for the Workflow Definition Language in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language) and subsequent guides.
- [Create, edit, or extend JSON for logic app workflow definitions in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-author-definitions).
- [Automate workflows for a SQL database by using Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure)

Once you have that, you can user [Logic App PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/az.logicapp) to create (New-AzLogicApp) / update (Set-AzLogicApp) your logic app. For example (params with [] are optional):

```
New-AzLogicApp
   -ResourceGroupName <String>
   -Name <String>
   -Location <String>
   [-State <String>]
   -Definition <Object>
   [-IntegrationAccountId <String>]
   [-Parameters <Object>]
   [-ParameterFilePath <String>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]

or

New-AzLogicApp
   -ResourceGroupName <String>
   -Name <String>
   -Location <String>
   [-State <String>]
   -DefinitionFilePath <String>
   [-IntegrationAccountId <String>]
   [-Parameters <Object>]
   [-ParameterFilePath <String>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Or you can use ARM template too. Refer [Overview: Automate deployment for Azure Logic Apps by using Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview).